# If A-B be in A-B A else B eh?

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic

Given two integers, A and B, output A if A-B (A minus B) is in A-B (A to B), otherwise output B.

"A minus B" is standard subtraction.

"A to B" is the range of integers starting at A and ending at B, including both A and B. For example:

```
1 to 4: 1, 2, 3, 4
-2 to 5: -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
3 to -1: 3, 2, 1, 0, -1
7 to 7: 7
```

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

### Test Cases

```
A B Output
1 4 4
-2 5 5
3 -1 -1
7 7 7
90 30 90
90 -30 -30
-90 30 30
-90 -30 -90
-2 -2 -2
-2 -1 -2
-2 0 -2
-2 1 1
-2 2 2
-1 -2 -2
-1 -1 -1
-1 0 -1
-1 1 1
-1 2 2
0 -2 -2
0 -1 -1
0 0 0
0 1 1
0 2 2
1 -2 -2
1 -1 -1
1 0 1
1 1 1
1 2 2
2 -2 -2
2 -1 -1
2 0 2
2 1 2
2 2 2
```

<sup>[Original Chat-Mini-Challenge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35909025#35909025)</sup>

Answer (score 45):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:[a,b][2*b*b>a*b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#VU/RaoQwEHyuXzEVBLWxJNpSTrC/0A@wPiSecsJVD6Mt9/U2MeaMsBtmdndms23xvVz5jzhzcCLyUj1VmcYiFp88FtXSjOMwShSgXjuMeobU6HoVt3kKo9zDvWhDVY48dC3q543l8J5uY9dP8L/mSc1Cy8NAkkBG@OMSCkJehvl6xoX/NhBN06viqx9oA3IndaQ8tv0vBZi3@QUSpuoj2BCWsmQEbyoqgjJJCd5VaJwRJEynJh8EOjQ8UYJM5YlalmTmWR1s26Gmb@b1BpMPxlxGXaI6zGIdK2YHA@b@UiPqkocB2w2oq6eunK5qukGrpbv0sPqw2Sy2kO3QSg9np67UHG3rbIertPoH)

An arithmetic formula. Why is the negation of `2*b*b>a*b` equivalent to the problem condition `a-b in symrange(a,b)`?

Note that `x in symrange(a,b)` is equivalent to `0 in symrange(a-x,b-x)`. Applying this to `x=a-b` gives `0 in symrange(b,2*b-a)`. The value `0` is included in the interval unless it stretches between two positive values or two negative values. This can be stated arithmetically as  "their product `b*(2*b-a)` is not positive.

Finally, take `b*(2*b-a)<=0`, and rewrite to `2*b*b<=a*b`. A byte is saved by flipping `<=` to `>` and switching the cases.

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
_erị,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#TY6xDcJQEENXQal94u4HFEUZgCGiKBULMAItg9BkA0omSRb56OfbKJXtuyfLeb4/1s8LeWi@7/P2XG45j4HLhNNoCdeiLSyKduiK9I7Waaw6@9/scEywJBM0@ihXIESGyCAZUN4BJ@jkvGIOpv2pNpWxi1Vs0jht4zQuK8N@)

#### How it works

```
_erị,  Main link. Arguments: a, b

_      Subtraction; Yield a-b.
  r    Range; yield [a, ..., b].
 e     Exists; yield 1 if a-b belongs to [a, ..., b], 0 if not.
    ,  Pair; yield [a, b].
   ị   At-index; yield the element of [a, b] at index 1 (a) or index 0 (b).
```

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

Code:

```
DŸ¹Æå_è
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@9ydMehnYfbDi@NP7zi//9oSwMdBWODWAA)

Explanation:

```
D         # Duplicate the input.
 Ÿ        # Inclusive range.
  ¹Æ      # Push the input [a, b] and compute a - b.
    å     # Check if the number exists in the range.
     _    # Boolean negate
      è   # Index at the first input
```

Comment: @Okx The CMC asked for a Boolean.

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, 58 Bytes

```
<?=in_array(($a=$argv[1])-$b=$argv[2],range($a,$b))?$a:$b;
```

Comment: The `$b` assignment needs no parentheses.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 24 bytes

```
a=>b=>[a,b][2*b*b>a*b|0]
```

### Test cases

```js
let f = a=>b=>[a,b][2*b*b>a*b|0]
let tests = [[1,4,4],[-2,5,5],[3,-1,-1],[7,7,7],[90,30,90],[90,-30,-30],[-90,30,30],[-90,-30,-90],[-2,-2,-2],[-2,-1,-2],[-2,0,-2],[-2,1,1],[-2,2,2],[-1,-2,-2],[-1,-1,-1],[-1,0,-1],[-1,1,1],[-1,2,2],[0,-2,-2],[0,-1,-1],[0,0,0],[0,1,1],[0,2,2],[1,-2,-2],[1,-1,-1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1],[1,2,2],[2,-2,-2],[2,-1,-1],[2,0,2],[2,1,2],[2,2,2]]
tests.map(test => `f(${test[0]})(${test[1]}) == ${test[2]}`).forEach(test => console.log(test, eval(test)))
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python2, <s>55</s> <s>52</s> 51 bytes

```
lambda A,B:[B,A][A-B in range(min(A,B),max(A,B)+1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#VZDBboMwDIbP5Ck8LhAtTElpNbVSDnDYK@zAOKQU2mhAK@iBt2e2F6RNDr9/nM8mZO1s74bzxUGhylNVqqKuiqwEP8LkxmubDn5McUuqwS1sXo2s19nGcWxgD3uR7eAAB5FDZnCJd8AQRw25hqMmk@X8iOy3GBxXEcB2XmxMMDpkA4YShuA9LpvwJVQdMnOGOR0wHSiNkEYlRDOxDdrm0BhSw0rEdqRdIOhA9GZYMfDnRXefoLnRRc1v86P3zzT5GhN5EpFTZ9XYyo/PdJFA3EJYc9s4SGQtIt9BlyIrwVposC96TNQTf96n7/byArECHiVF1PZz@4f4cL7/R6w/)

Handles every test case OP has mentioned (at the time of posting this), as the TIO suggests.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 37 bytes

```
lambda*s:s[min(s)<=s[1]-s[0]<=max(s)]
```

Invoke as `f(B, A)`.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript ES6, <strike>40</strike> 37 bytes

```
a=>b=>a-b<(a<b?a:b)|a-b>(a<b?b:a)?b:a
```

Explained:

```
a=>b=>                                   take a and b as inputs
      a-b<(a<b?a:b)                      if a-b is less than the lowest of a and b
                   |a-b>(a<b?b:a)        or a-b is greater than the largest of a and b
                                 ?b      return b
                                   :a    else return a
```

Saved 3 bytes thanks to Arnauld.

```js
f=a=>b=>a-b<(a<b?a:b)|a-b>(a<b?b:a)?b:a

function t(){
    var tests = [[1,4,4],[-2,5,5],[3,-1,-1],[7,7,7],[90,30,90],[90,-30,-30],[-90,30,30],[-90,-30,-90],[-2,-2,-2],[-2,-1,-2],[-2,0,-2],[-2,1,1],[-2,2,2],[-1,-2,-2],[-1,-1,-1],[-1,0,-1],[-1,1,1],[-1,2,2],[0,-2,-2],[0,-1,-1],[0,0,0],[0,1,1],[0,2,2],[1,-2,-2],[1,-1,-1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1],[1,2,2],[2,-2,-2],[2,-1,-1],[2,0,2],[2,1,2],[2,2,2]];
    for (var test of tests) {
        console.log(`f(${test[0]},${test[1]}) == ${test[2]}`, f(test[0])(test[1])==test[2]);
    }
}

t();
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 16 bytes

```
If[2#^2>1##,##]&
```

Pure function taking two arguments in the opposite order as the OP (for example, `If[2#^2>1##,##]&[B,A]`). A port of [xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112334/56178).

Answer (score 2):

### R, <s>49</s> <s>30</s> 28 bytes

```
pryr::f("if"(2*b*b>a*b,b,a))
```

Uses @xnor's logic for determining whether a-b is in a:b.

Comment: unnamed functions are generally allowed

Comment: You can lose another 3 bytes using `pryr::f(match(a-b,a:b,b))`

Comment: @mnel thanks for sharing that, I didn't know how %in% worked before; but that fails whenever a-b is in a:b. f(-90,-30) = 31

Comment: Indeed. `pryr::f(match(a-b,a:b,0)+b) fixes that (and still saves a byte.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, <s>71</s> 41 bytes

-30 bytes by using `<=` and `min`/`max` instead of `range`s.

```clj
#(if(<=(min % %2)(- % %2)(max % %2))% %2)
```

Checks if `(a - b)` is in the range from `a` to `b`, dispatching a return accordingly.

```clj
(defn eh [a b]
  ; <= accepts any number of argments, and ensures all fall within the range
    (if (<= (min a b) (- a b) (max a b))
      a
      b))
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP (7.1), 55 bytes

uses the [new](http://php.net/manual/migration71.new-features.php) array destructuring syntax:

```php
[,$a,$b]=$argv;echo in_array($a-$b,range($a,$b))?$a:$b;
```

Run with `-r`, provide numbers as command line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>37</s> <s>35</s> 32 bytes

```powershell
($a,$b=$args)[$a-$b-notin$a..$b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6@hkqijkmSrkliUXqwZrZKoq5Kkm5dfkpmnkqinp5IU@///f12j/4YA)

Literal translation of the problem into PowerShell using the `-notin` operator. Saved three bytes by using multiple assignment and encapsulation. This works because `-` has a [higher operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence) than `-notin`, and the `( )` portion of the code is executed first and returned as an array `@($a,$b)`. However, since it's `$a,$b` rather than `$b,$a`, we need to use `-notin` to flip/flop the output result.

Answer (score 2):

## Nim, 60 bytes

```
proc f(a,b:int):int=
  if a-b in min(a,b)..max(a,b):a else:b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/nim#XZLdioMwEIXvfYpDryrEkuguS4VA38P1IhZlhfUHW4pvbzOJ7iYDM@F8M8kxhtnmZbqjOxvRlP34TGnRCdB3MFmDfsTQj9RNL5fBrE6VBu3voy2b7WUWzGYxw0PjVtljt0oJfNiohaMsF/i0sWMhkCnKnb8EKHa6SoHC5lUGhazwy2F4bIorftffQfqsz7CgWEEytn0VIMWBivsp9icEknHopyI/yewkc5POTP5TYCUjJ34xfi9/rYBURIETf7KcOfkHC7oqIueU1Ek32ZGgufFzUdq@nRK7AkZjrmTtdENaeb2Szkm3958JRuD0/TwJNIdw45lCa6zbGw)

Pretty standard as far as answers go, no big tricks in this one.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 107 bytes

```
@set/aa=%1,r=b=%2,x=a-b
@if %a% gtr %b% set/aa=b,b=%1
@if %a% leq %x% if %x% leq %b% set/ar=%1
@echo %r%
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 9 bytes

Was hoping to use more implicit input... :(

```
@Q!}-FQ}F
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40Q%21%7D-FQ%7DF&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%2C+4%0A-2%2C+5&debug=0).

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 30 bytes

```
f a,b{[b]if[2*b*b>a*b]else[a]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/roda#RY7RboMwDEWfl6@wEA/AQEqg1dRN7H3fQFGbsGRD6igiTKrU8e3M9oImJ9fOzYmd1YHOzb0xbe@aMjOZedWZae3F20a3y/ql@wHu4mH89p/JbP186rS3PoUf8OOlnxNvxzo6Hv1jRN6oJ2/fhtl@2AlOaLjrRAPyDt6vcKtdgof0BcapH2Y4uyTWeWxSqCG@kXRn5AYrFiFw6P88eK4hUrCDnShK2MNeVFAoXOIJMMRBQiXhIKkoKt6i@DNDxS4C@JwXFyoUMmQFihKG4Du2VZiEKkNmTjEnAyYDJRGSqIRIJrZGWx9qQ6pYidi@VAaCPkQnxYoRiWX9BQ)

It uses the formula used in xnor's answer.

Another solution (37 bytes):

```
f a,b{[a]if[a-b in[seq(a,b)]]else[b]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/roda#RY5hboMwDIV/L6d4QvygGkhJaTV1EwfYGShqAwsbUkcZYVKljrMz2wuanDw7L1/sLC1sWt9LW3VtabMaXV9695WQuakqd/GurKt5@bRdj7t6GL79RzI5P50a653f4Ad@uHRT4t1QRMejf4zYG@zo3Ws/uXc34kRGex15Ttrg7Ypb0Ur/Fwxj1084t0ls07jeoEB8Y2nOxPVOzUrR0P95eC4QGeywU9kWe@xVjszQUk@gUAeNXOOguchy2Sr7M0MlLgH0XJYUJhQ6ZAPDiULJndgmTCLVIQtnhNMB04HSBGlSRrQQa6O1D7dhNaJMrF/aBoI/xCcjShGpefkF)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>84</s> <s>60</s> 58 bytes

```java
int c(int a,int b){return(a<b?a:b)>a-b|(a<b?b:a)<a-b?b:a;}
```

## Java 8, 37 bytes

```java
a->b->(a<b?a:b)>a-b|(a<b?b:a)<a-b?b:a
```

**Explanation:**

```java
int c(int a, int b){          // method with two integer parameters and integer return-type
  return (a<b ? a : b) > a-b  //  if smallest of the input is larger than a-b
       | (a<b ? b : a) < a-b  //    or if the largest of the input is smaller than a-b
    ? b                       //   return b
    :                         //  else
      a                       //   return a
}                             // end of method
```

**Test code:** [Try it here.](https://ideone.com/mYsUsN)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 21 bytes

Makes use of @xnor's [trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112334/63647). We use `-v B A` to prepopulate the stack. (`-v A B` is +1 byte).

```
:01pr:11p::2**r*)1gn;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@29lYFhQZGVoWGBlZaSlVaSlaZieZ/3//3/dMgUTEGEIAA)

### Explanation

```
                        Input: [B, A] on stack.
:01pr:11p::2**r*)1gn;
:                       Duplicate.           [B, A, A]
 01p                    Push A to [0,1].     [B, A]
    r                   Reverse              [A, B]
     :                  Duplicate.           [A, B, B]
      11p               Push B to [1,1].     [A, B]
         ::             Duplicate x 2.       [A, B, B, B]
           2            Push 2.              [A, B, B, B, 2]
           2**          Compute 2*B*B.       [A, B, 2*B*B]
              r         Reverse.             [2*B*B, B, A]
               *        Compute A*B.         [2*B*B, A*B]
                )       >                    [2*B*B > A*B]
                 1      Push 1.              [2*B*B > A*B, 1]
                  g     If 2*B*B > A*B
                         get B, else get A.  [2*B*B > A*B ? B : A]
                   n    Output as number.
                    ;   Terminate.
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Swift](https://swift.org/about/) - <del>38</del> <s>30</s>  22 bytes

<sup>Saved 8 bytes thanks to @Matt</sup>

```swift
print(a...b~=a-b ?a:b)
```

[Try it at IBM Swift Sandbox online!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/58c18fe9f8ba897c77f93546)

---

### Or 21 bytes:

<sup>(thanks to **@xnor**'s formula) and saved 8 bytes thanks to @Matt</sup>

```swift
print(2*b*b>a*b ?a:b)
```

---

Swift is not the best language for golfing (it's very rigid), so if you see any other golfing opportunity, I'll totally edit the answer.

Comment: Why not put the ternary inside the print like print(a...b~=a-b ? a : b)

Comment: Oh, yes, good ideA. Thanks @Matt

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>27</s> 22 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{(b*a<2*b*b)?b:a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@59mq2uXqJNUrZGklWhjpJWklaRpn2SVWMvFVaCQFm1poGNsEAtj6sLYukjiulCJ//8B)

Nothing innovative here. The simple math behind it:

```ruby
(A<=A-B<=B or B<=A-B<=A)
```

can be written as

```ruby
(B>=0 and A>=2B) or (B<=0 and A<=2B)
```

that is: if A-2B has the same sign as B, we are in the range.

Answer (score 1):

## SpecBAS - 38 btes

```
1 INPUT a,b: ?IIF(a-b IN [a TO b],a,b)
```

`IIF` is an inline-IF-THEN-ELSE, to print the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 21 bytes

```
a!b|b*a<2*b*b=b|0<1=a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@omFSTpJVoY6SVpJVkm1RjYGNom/g/NzEzT8FWISWfSwEICooy80oUVBQMFRQVTFBENHSNNIGCpiiClgZAIWMDTDENXWMDzf8A)

### Readable

```
func :: Int -> Int -> Int
func a b
    | b*a < 2*b*b = b
    | otherwise = a
```

### Explanation

Uses @xnor's formula to check whether a-b is in range. Nothing special besides that.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 7 - 45 Bytes

```
echo(in_array($a-$b,range($a,$b))?$a:$b)==$c;
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 58 bytes

Just recently I fell in love with arrows again. Unfortunately they require us to work with tuples instead of binary functions. And of course Haskell does not have a symmetrical `range` function.

```
import Control.Arrow
u=uncurry
app<<<elem.u(-)&&&(u enumFromTo<<<u min&&&u max)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 55bytes

```
@(a,b)(c=b*~[find((a:1-2*(b<a):b)==(a-b)) 0](1))+(a*~c)
```

This could probably be optimised further. I'll add an explanation later.

Comment: [A simpler approach](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113360/31516). +1 for all the "crazy stuff" in there though :P

Answer (score 1):

## Ti-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE), <s>26 24</s> 23 bytes

```
Prompt A,B
A-B≥A and A-B≤B
AAns+Bnot(Ans
```

TI-Basic is a tokenized language; all tokens used are [one-byte tokens](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens).

`Prompt` prompts you for the two numbers.

`A-B≥A and A-B≤B` checks if A-B is between A and B (inclusive); this returns a 1 if true and a zero if false, which is stored to `Ans`.

Since we are returning A if A-B is between A and B, we multiply A by Ans, which will be A if we are supposed to return A, and 0 otherwise.

Next, we add `Bnot(Ans` to it. If Ans was 1 (truthy), we `not(` it and get 0, thus our sum is A. If Ans was 0 (falsy), we `not(` it to get 1, which we multiply by B and add to 0 to get B.

The last evaluation in TI-Basic is implicitly returned.

-2 bytes thanks to Scott Milner

Comment: You can save two bytes by not storing the third line to `Y` and just using `Ans` in the fourth line.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 32 bytes

```
←Đ←Đ3Ș⇹Đ3ȘĐ4Ș3Ș-3Ș⇹Ř∈Đ3Ș⇹¢*3Ș⇹*+
```

Takes A and B from stdin as two separate inputs

Explanation:

AABB -> ABBA -> ABAB -> ABABB -> ABBBA -> ABBBAA -> ABAABB -> ABABBA -> ABABC -> ABCBA -> ABCAB -> ABC[A,...,B] -> ABD -> ABDD -> ADDB -> ADBD -> AD{B*(1-D)} -> {B*(1-D)}AD -> {B*(1-D)}+{A*D}

where:  C=B-A and D=C∈[A,...,B] (1 if true, 0 if false)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 10 bytes (CP437)

There's probably a golfier way to do this, but the strictly-typed nature of Ruby makes this difficult.

```
G┼┘-îε?┼¿┘
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>31 29</s>  24 bytes

```perl6
{$^a-$^b==any($a...$b)??$a!!$b}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#NY5NbsIwEIX3PsUDRSURcbAJtEIopLDrnmWElB9XRYIENaEqinKy7nqnrunY2Br7zeT5m8lcW4Wv56hcs/MNT2VTKST33jvk3DsUSZLXN9/LoyjyiiBNvXw08orhfqWmvWo70/TaUdUiwelYq9YPfn@isjkX/mzCJ2lWTWfaeasJvpzyGtMHv2bvzafr5Rsf2TZEtqOrvi@q7FSFoGfAsYVeyt@GuyCEewsx7skZkGzQO3MYs@EuscCC8TmWWLIYXNJhL6BgK4FYYCV0wWNzGX@YtjIuAdRujimkLYTNElInCmbejC3tn0iFzYaThhMWE5YSBAlSjQhDuEFujh6jVRrVhFtpbgm9kP6SRin@6oaXefmh/gE)

```perl6
{$^a-$^b∈($a...$b)??$a!!$b}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#NY5NbsIwEIX3PsUDRSURcbAJtEIopLDrnmWElB9XRYIENaFqFWXPnbrrUXqHrtOxcTT2m8nzN5O51gofj0G@ZucvPORVoRD1rXNIuXPIfm8310mDIHAyL46ddDRysq6/Uste1Y1peW6oqhHhdCxV7Xo/30FenTN3NuGTOCmmM@28lARfTmmJ6Z1fs9fqfejlGxfJ1keyo6s@LypvVAGvZcCxhl7J3fo7z8fw5mPcktMh2qAdzG7Mul5igQXjcyyxZCG4pMOeQMFWAqHASuiCh@YyfjdtZVwCqN0cU0hbCJslpE4UzLwZW9o/kQqbDScNJywmLCUIEqQaEYYYBg1z9Bit0qgmhpXmltAL6S9plOKvrHie5m/qHw)

```perl6
->\a,\b{2*b*b>a*b??b!!a}
->\a,\b{2*b²>a*b??b!!a}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#NY5NbsIwEIX3PsWDRUlCDHYCrRBKUth132U2@XFVJEhQE6pWUU7WXe/UdTo2tsZ@M37@PJ5bp/D5uKr27PKNh6qtFZKJp3kR5uUQBWVQpkVQZlk5mxXjdCP6VXW9oZ97qjokOJ8a1Xn@78@qai@lt17wRZbXy7V2XhqCr@eiwfLO79lb@@He8tRDfgiRH2mrr6uqelXDHxhw6qCn8Q7h0Q/h7kLMB3JGJCkGZ45zNk4SG2wYj7DFlsXgkhZ7AgXbCcQCO6ELHpvN@N20lXEJoOdmmULaQtgsIXWiYObO2NL@RCpsNpw0nLCYsJQgSJBqRBjCNXJ9dBut0qgm3EiRJfRA@iSNUvw1La@K6l39Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## Kotlin, 43 bytes

```
{a,b->if(a-b in a..b||a-b in b..a)a else b}
```

This is the one time that I am grateful that kotlin ranges are inclusive.

You could alternatively do it using xnor's algorithm with 28 bytes:

```
{a,b->if(2*b*b>a*b)b else a}
```

[Test Suite](https://tio.run/nexus/kotlin#jZDfa8IwEMff81fcRDARW5OqDN3s2MMeBoOBexQfEta6QM2k1o1R@7e7yzV1DPawpL1f@dw3R86M5UcHO20d1@X2AAu4L0v9dftSldZtU8FqBrg@dAE5HvJHV40AjYAo9R6WUOuRiVKbcx0ZsA50HJvTKSQmjrXQkBWHDExDWuPxv9SSoRmaVA@NMG27bhj1f77ZIgNelcdMUKEdsRuzsC5DnTLTr08YcgF3C8yqY@l@cYd9Yf2Fno8p4QMYiHin91CDreLqHSfC9nCtXzYHnnOC13IzajXWaiPgahmSZCMu@M9gfu3xRavC8d7DavW8gj4N2q//1Gt64ubS3D5bw5rzWcEUpixKYAYzNoFI4ceuATebS5hImEsfRBP6WdQWQ0RVBLCdPgpUCGTwCpR3uBmdUVmFm9DK4IlTxMmAyUBJhCRaj0giOqFOx8t4q8h6ohspCYQfyGeKLO5v)

Answer (score 0):

## MATL, 13 bytes

```
tPdGSl&)&:mo)
```

Try it at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=tPdGSl%26%29%26%3Amo%29&inputs=%5B90+30%5D&version=19.8.0)

**Explanation**

```
    % Implicitly grab input as a 2-element array
t   % Duplicate the input
Pd  % Flip the order and compute the difference
GS  % Grab the input again and sort it
l&) % Break the two elements of the array into two stack elements
&:  % Create the array from the smaller to the larger element
m   % Check for membership (returns FALSE or TRUE)
o   % Convert FALSE to 0 and TRUE to 1
)   % Use this as a modular index into the initial array
    % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 bytes

```
òV bU-V ¨0?U:V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@394U5hCUqhumMKhFQb2oVZh///rWhooGBsAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 25 bytes

```
IIGÉ┼┘-E;?┼¿┘;,
```

Expanation:

```
IIGÉ┼┘-E;?┼¿┘;,
II              ■Inputs twice
  G             ■Range a..b
   É            ■any {
    ┼┘-E        ■  firstInput-secondInput==element
        ;       ■}
         ? ¿ ;  ■if {
          ┼     ■  firstinput
           ¿    ■}else{
            ┘   ■  secondinput
             ;  ■}
              , ■Print
```

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, 49 bytes

*-2 bytes because Google Sheets automatically closes brackets*

```
=MINUS(A1,A2
=IF(AND(GTE(A1,A3),LTE(A2,A3)),A1,A2
```

Inputs are in the cells A1 and A2. Assumes cell A3 is selected after input is recieved.

The newline isn't actually a newline, it's just pressing enter.

The code is pretty readable, so I doubt an explanation is needed.

Answer (score 0):

## Octave, <s>37</s> 34 bytes

```
@(a)a(2-ismember(-diff(a),a:a(2)))
```

This is an anonymous function that takes the input values as an array of two elements: `[-90, 30]`.

**Breakdown:**

```
@(a)a(                           )  % Function that takes a variable a as input
                                    % and returns the x'th element (dependent on what's
                                    % inside the parentheses.
                 -diff(a)           % Takes the negative difference between the two

                          a:a(2)))  % A vector: -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 ...
        ismember(-diff(a),a:a(2)))  % Checks if the negative difference (a-b)
                                       % is part of the range. Returns 1 for true
    a(2-ismember(-diff(a),a:a(2)))  % Return the 2-ismember() element of the input
@(a)a(2-ismember(-diff(a),a:a(2)))  % Everything put together
```

`a(1):a(2)` is the same as `a:a(2)` since Octave automatically assumes you want the first element. That saved an additional two bytes.

I *could* save one more byte by taking the input in the different order `[b, a]`, but I figured it was cleaner this way.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 39 bytes

```
nn&s<l>>lRy![plfR11$]p<-s>l~[<<pu;]<<u;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z8vT63YJsfOLieoUjG6ICctyNBQJbbARrfYLqcu2samoNQ61sam1Pr/f0sDLmMDAA)