# Calculate a square and a square root!

Tags: code-golf, math, polyglot

You must make a [polyglot](/questions/tagged/polyglot) that outputs the square of the input in one language and the square root of the input in another. The shortest answer in bytes wins!

You must have a precision of at least 3 decimal places, and the input will always be a positive float.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf/) and [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 1 byte

```
U
```

Square root in Jolf, square in MATL.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P/T/fxM9UwA) (MATL)

[Try the Jolf code.](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=VQ&input=NC41) Only works on Firefox.

These are both 1 byte, as MATL and Jolf both use ASCII/extended ASCII codepages, so all commands are 1 byte.

Answer (score 98):

## C and C++, <s>68</s> 65 bytes

```c
#include<math.h>
float f(float n){auto p=.5;return pow(n,2-p*3);}
```

Original answer:

```c
#include<math.h>
float f(float n){return pow(n,sizeof('-')-1?2:.5);}
```

For both versions, C produces `n^2` and C++ produces `sqrt(n)`.

Comment: +1 as a "Ha!" for all those people who treat C and C++ as the same thing.

Comment: How does C interpret this to get n^2? Does `p` get set to `0`? I'm reading it like C++ would and have no idea how C interprets it differently.

Comment: @CAD97: In C, `auto` means "allocate on the stack". The keyword is fairly useless because that's the default anyway, so C++ repurposed it to mean something else. In C, though, it doesn't express any opinion about the type of `p` (it's a storage class, not a type), so it counts as an `int` by default (this default-to-`int` behaviour is discouraged nowadays, and likely only exists because some of C's predecessors didn't have data types at all, but compilers still understand it). And of course, `(int)0.5` is 0.

Comment: This is brilliant.

Comment: How is `sizeof('-')` interpreted differently in C and C++? Is `'-'` an `int` in C?

Comment: @YSC It does [seem like that's the case](http://ideone.com/r9iKZU) for C, for C++ [it's 1 indeed](http://ideone.com/eymh8G)

Comment: Found a [Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars) about it.

Comment: Been writing C for donkey's years, never seen "auto" before.  Awesome.

Comment: I think the explanation for this answer would be improved by editing in @ais523's comment explaining _why_ C produces `n^2`.

Comment: @BrianJ normally I put a full explanation in my answers, but in this case I found so many unexpected differences between the languages that I think it's more interesting for people to look up what's going on for themselves and stumble across some of the others.

Comment: The repurposing of `auto` in C++ was introduced in 2011.  For all C++ standards before 2011, the version using `auto` would produce the same in both C and C++.   The `sizeof` version works for all C and C++ standards.

Comment: What about `#include<math.h> #define f(n) pow(n,sizeof('-')*1.5-1)`? It seems to be shorter than both. Or do codegolf rules recommend using functions instead of preprocessor macros?

Comment: @Sasha `sizeof('-')*1.5-1` wouldn't work unless the machine has a 16-bit `int`: it gives 5 if `int` is 32-bit or 11 if `int` is 64-bit. As for using macros rather than functions, you'd have to check meta for confirmation, but I haven't seen it done.

Comment: @Dave, you're right. Then `#include<math.h> #define f(n) pow(n,sizeof('-')>1?2:.5)`. It's anyway shorter.

Comment: `sizeof` doesn't need parentheses, so the longer version could just be `sizeof'-'-1?...` (or indeed with `>`), but that's still longer than the `auto` version.

Answer (score 55):

## Python 2 & Python 3, <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```python
lambda n:n**(1/2or 2)
```

Python 2.x produces `n^2`, Python 3.x produces `sqrt(n)`.

<sub>2 bytes saved thanks to @Dennis!</sub>

Comment: this is so cool!

Comment: Why? Is it the lack of space before `or`?

Comment: @chx In Py2, `/` does integer division (`1/2==0`). In Py3, it does floating point division (`1/2==0.5)`. `0` is falsey.

Comment: then why not remove the space after or?

Comment: @chx Try it yourself. It throws a syntax error if you do.

Comment: @chx removing the space after `or` will cause python to read `or2` as a function or variable name.  You can remove the space before `or` though, as python variables/functions can't start with a number, so `2or` is parsed as `2 or`.

Answer (score 34):

## [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable) / [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
*.
```

2sable computes the square. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/2sable#@6@l9/@/oQEA)

Jelly computes the square root. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@6@l9///f0MDAA)

### How it works

#### 2sable

```
*   Read the input twice and compute the product of both copies.
    This pushes the square of the input.
 .  Unrecognized token (ignored).
```

#### Jelly

```
 .  Numeric literal; yield 0.5.
*   Raise the input to the power 0.5.
    This yields the square root.
```

Comment: It's like these languages were created *just* for this challenge

Answer (score 19):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/) and [Python](http://www.python.org), <s>109</s> <s>107</s> <s>69</s> 53 bytes

```c
#/*
lambda n:n**.5;'''*/
float a(i){return i*i;}//'''
```

C: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-clang#LYtBCoMwEEX3niIommQQAy3dNHiY0RgY0GmJ6Sp49jRClv@993NnoNnxWBwKfjPA9LJSSjCN3z8YBSrSKWzxF1gQkL2MKToTR3EgsdKphs6eK7JXbe/bcXDaVk6PGdU9v6Gcqi@0kCs//w)

Python: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@6@sr8WVk5iblJKokGeVp6WlZ2qtrq6upc@VlpOfWKKQqJGpWV2UWlJalKeQqZVpXauvD5T@n2aLqoeroCgzr0QhTSMzr6C0RENT878lAA)

Works by using comments to polyglot. The rest is pretty explanatory.

First time using C!

- Saved quite a few bytes thanks to @Riker.
- Saved 2 bytes by removing unnecessary whitespace.
- Saved very many bytes by using a function for C instead of STDIN/OUT.
- Saved 16 bytes thanks to @Delioth by removing import statement at the top.

Comment: I believe you can remove one newline after the C comment (line 2, last character) since C doesn't need whitespace and it's already a literal string for python. Since you aren't returning any special code, you can omit the `return 0;` from the end- C99 holds an implicit return of 0 on `main()` specifically. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/207992/6480793)

Comment: @Delioth It actually made more sense just to use the function, and wipe out the io.

Comment: Oh, yeah- much better. Do you even need to include `stdio.h` in that case?

Comment: @Delioth I don't. Whoops!

Answer (score 18):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm) and [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

Outputs the square in Ohm, the square root in Jelly.

Ohm and Jelly use different single-byte codepages, so the program will appear differently in each encoding.

xxd hexdump of the program:

```
00000000: fd7f 0a                                  ...
```

#### Jelly

Using Jelly's codepage, it appears like this:

```
’
½
```

Jelly takes the bottom most line to be its main link, and ignores the other links unless specifically called. So here it just does the square root (`½`) and implicitly outputs it.

#### Ohm

Using Ohm's codepage (CP437), it appears like this:

```
²⌂◙
```

`²` is the square function, and `⌂` and `◙` are both undefined, so the program just squares the implicitly read input and implicitly outputs it.

Comment: Nice! The byte count is fine.

Comment: I edited my answer to 5 bytes because of this as well, good catch.

Comment: Wow, the first Ohm answer not written by me! Well done!

Comment: If you use the Jelly code page to get the `½` at a byte, what does the `²` map to? Is it just junk that is still ignored? And vice-versa for Ohm? Then it would seem to be 2 bytes.

Comment: Both of those chars are in Jelly's code page and in Ohm's codepage it should seem... So those count as single bytes. If you don't need the space and the newlines I agree with @AdmBorkBork

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Are you saying I should take Ohm's codepoint for `²` and use the Jelly character at that codepoint? (or vice versa)

Comment: I'll make up an example, since I don't want to bother looking up the actual code points. Suppose that `²` in Ohm is at code point 5. Code point 5 in Jelly is `%` and does nothing, so it doesn't matter what the first line is. Suppose that `½` in Jelly is at 27, and code point 27 in Ohm is `J` and does nothing, so it doesn't matter what the second line is. Thus, if you have a file of `00000101<newline>00011011`, it's 3 bytes. I guess the only problem is if the newline is at a different location in the code pages.

Comment: @NickClifford I did one too. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112657/56341

Comment: @RomanGräf Whoa, you've really been using the language a lot! Guess I'm just blind or something :P

Answer (score 14):

## C89 and C99, 47+3 = 50 bytes

```c
float f(float n){return n//*
/sqrt(n)//*/1*n
;}
```

Requires `-lm` flag (+3)

C89 produces `n^2`, C99 produces `sqrt(n)`. To test in C89, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#JYtBDoIwEADvfUWDMekSodGTBPUlXprCapOyaLucCF93bcJpZg4jGGfHGs1OgjWNvCTSZG2tbP4mNgTF7bkm1W/qEMjHZRhvmYcwt@@HCsR6coEMrJ9UAk11jPik6oTmAtBvIj@P0b2yNGW6@2snTZz@)

---

Getting C89 to do the `sqrt` version ought to take less code, but it insists on implicitly declaring the `sqrt` function with `int`s, so this is the best I could manage.

Answer (score 13):

## Octave / MATLAB, <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```
 @(x)x^(2-3*any(version>60)/2)
```

This outputs the square in Octave, and the square root in MATLAB.

**Explanation:**

The syntax is of course identical in MATLAB and Octave (for this little piece of code at least).

This creates an anonymous function:

```
@(x)                                 % Take x as input
    x^(                     )        % Raise x to the power of ...   
               version                 % Returns the version number
                                       % 4.2.0 in Octave, 
                                       % '9.2.0.538062 (R2017a)' in MATLAB
               version>60              % 'R' is larger than 60. All others are smaller
         3*any(version>60)/2           % Checks if there is an 'R' and multiplies it by 1.5 if it is.
       2-3*any(version>60)           % 2-1.5*(is there an 'R')
```

Answer (score 12):

## Basic / Delphi – 6 characters

```
sqr(x)
```

Square root in Basic and square in Delphi.

You can use a debugger to inspect the expression, thereby fulfilling any output requirements!

Comment: Does this take input by itself?

Comment: No, but neither do some other submissions, including the C/C++ one.

Comment: Still invalid though, that doesn't change anything. I'll try to comment on those also.

Comment: Can you link any that don't? I can't find any. The C/C++ one is a function, doesn't take input, instead a parameter.

Comment: `sqr` is a function as well, and takes a parameter. It happens to be built-in like some of the golfing languages.

Comment: Yes, but what is `x`? You can't assume it's saved to a value. But you might actually be able to remove the `(x)`, and label it as returning a function.

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) / [Fireball](https://github.com/okx-code/Fireball), 3 bytes

The following bytes make up the program:

```
FD B9 74
```

05AB1E calculates square root, Fireball squares.

Explanation (05AB1E - `ý¹t`):

```
ý       Pushes an empty string to the stack (not entirely sure why)
 ¹      Push first input
  t     Square root
```

Explanation (Fireball - `²╣t`):

```
²       Square input
 ╣      Unassigned
  t     Unassigned
```

Sometimes, it helps to have an incomplete language ;)

Comment: 05AB1E and Fireball use different encodings. Does this affect the programs?

Comment: @Dennis I didn't think about that. So saving the same program in different encodings doesn't count for polygots?

Comment: Afaik, the default is that the byte streams must match.

Answer (score 10):

## PHP7 + JavaScript, <s>62</s> <s>61</s> 58 bytes

This was actually more challenging than I expected!  I am quite surprised of how long my code is.

```js
eval(['alert((_=prompt())*_)','echo$argv[1]**.5'][+![]]);
```

---

**How does it work?**

This works by selecting the code to run, from the array.
PHP and JavaScript detection is made with `+![]`.

In PHP, `[]` (empty array) is a falsy value, while in JavaScript it is a truthy value (objects (except `null`) are always truthy, even `new Boolean(false)` is truthy!).
But, I need to get it to a numeric value, so, I just use a `not` (`!`) and convert it to integer (with the `+`).
Now, PHP yields the value `1`, while JavaScript yields `0`.
Placing the code inside an array, at those indexes, will allow us to select the right code for the desired language.
This can be used as `[JS,PHP][+![]]`, to get the code of the right language.

On previous polyglots, I've used `'\0'=="\0"`, which is `true` in JavaScript (since `\0` is parsed as the NULL-byte) and `false` in PHP (the `'\0'` won't be parsed as the NULL-byte, comparing the literal string `\0` with the NULL-byte).
I'm happy that I've managed to reduce this check to `+!'0'`.
I'm even more happy about [@rckd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68084/rckd), which reduced it to the current version!

From there on, it simply `eval`s the code required.

**PHP**

PHP will execute `echo$argv[1]**.5` (equivalent to `echo sqrt($argv[1]);`, square-root the number), receiving the value from the 2nd argument and displays it in the standard output.

**JavaScript**

JavaScript executes `alert((_=prompt())*_)`, which displays the squared number in an `alert`.

---

---

Thank you to [@rckd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68084/rckd) for saving 1 byte, and [@user59178](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59178/user59178) for saving 3 bytes!

Comment: ![] will save you 1 byte :-)

Comment: @rckd Holy cow! Totally forgot about empty arrays. Thank you! I've edited into the question, with an explanation on how it works.

Comment: you can save 3 bytes by using `echo$argv[1]**.5` rather than `echo sqrt($argv[1])`

Comment: Wow, nice saving! Thank you! I've added it into the answer.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) and [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
nqƓ½
```

[(05AB1E)](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@59XeGzyob3//xt9zcvXTU5MzkgFAA) - [(Jelly)](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@59XeGzyob3//5sAAA)

```
nq   # Ignored by Jelly, push n**2 in 05AB1E then quit.
  Ɠ½ # Ignored by 05AB1E due to quit, push sqroot of input in Jelly.
```

---

Someone else made a good point, I guess since the UTF-8 characters do not share the same operation across code pages that they are technically 2-bytes each to encode. However, when looking at this in terms of the hex dump:

```
6e 71 93 0a
```

In 05AB1E's CP1252 encoding this results in:

```
nq“\n
```

Meaning it will still output the square and quit, ignoring the rest. When these bytes are encoded using Jelly's codepage:

```
nqƓ½
```

Which is the original intended code, when executed, results in the desired result of taking the input and taking the sqrt.

Comment: This is actually 6 bytes in UTF-8, as both `Ɠ` and `½` require two bytes to be encoded. However, the byte sequence `6e 71 93 0a` (`nqƓ½` for Jelly, `nq“\n` for CP-1252) should work in both languages.

Comment: @Dennis `½` being on both code-pages doesn't allow for it to count as a single because they're different operations I assume? I'm still fuzzy on the whole code-page thing.

Comment: Scoring in bytes means were counting byte streams. Unless the interpreter actually supports encoding some characters in one code page and other characters in another, we cannot do this for scoring purposes.

Comment: @carusocomputing your submission is the 4 bytes `6e 71 93 0a` so there's no "theoretically" about claiming 4 bytes. Just claim 4 bytes. It just so happens that in 05AB1E's standard encoding, it reads one thing which does what you want, while in Jelly's standard encoding, it reads another which does what you want. As an aside, just because 2 encodings can encode the same character doesn't mean that character will be the same in both of them. Just think of encodings like a numeric cypher with a lookup table already shared and hopefully that'll give you a good starting mental-model.

Comment: @Dave I must've misinterpreted Dennis then.

Comment: It's actually 4 bytes, you can remove 6 bytes entirely from the header. The byte stream is `6e 71 93 0a`.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2 and Forth, <s>43</s> 33 bytes

```python
( """ )
fsqrt
\ """);lambda n:n*n
```

**Try it online: [Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@6@hoKSkpKDJlVZcWFTCFQPiaVqn2eYk5ialJCrkWeVp5f0vKMrMK1FI0zDWMzQx1PwPAA) (square) | [Forth](https://tio.run/nexus/forth-gforth#MzY0MUzVNf6voaCkpKSgyZVWXFhUwhUD4mla5yTmJqUkKuRZ5Wnl/U/T@w8A) (sqrt)**

This evaluates to an anonymous function in Python, and a built-in function `fsqrt` in Forth. Python can have a named function `f` for 2 bytes more by putting `f=` in front of the lambda.

The Forth program takes a [floating point literal](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Floating-Point-Tutorial.html), which in Forth must be written in scientific notation. Pi truncated to 3 decimal places (`3.141`) would be written like this:

```
3141e-3
```

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/) / [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
ld_*GX^!
```

Computes the square in CJam ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@5@TEq/lHhGn@P@/kYGekSkA)) and the square root in MATL ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@5@TEq/lHhGn@P@/kYGekSkA)).

#### Explanation of square in CJam

```
ld    e# Read input line and interpret as a double
_     e# Duplicate
*     e# Multiply. Pops the input number twice, pushes its square
G     e# Push 16
X     e# Push 1
^     e# Bitwise XOR. Pops 16 and 1, and pushes 17
!     e# Negate. Pops 17, pushes 0
      e# Implicitly display. This prints the squared input with decimals,
      e# immediately followed by the 0 coming from the negate operation
      e# Even if the square of the input number is an integer, say 5,
      e# it is displayed as 5.0, so including an extra 0 always gives a
      e# correct result
```

#### Explanation of square root in MATL

```
l      % Push 1. This is a number or equivalently a 1×1 array
d      % Consecutive differences. Pops 1, pushes [] (empty array)
_      % Negate (element-wise). This leaves [] as is
*      % Implicitly input a number and push it. Multiply (element-wise): 
       % pops [] and the input number, pushes []
G      % Push input number again
X^     % Square root. Pops number, pushes its square root
!      % Transpose. For a number (1×1 array) this does nothing
       % Implicitly display. The stack contains [] and the result; but 
       % [] is not displayed at all
```

Comment: Hey! Nice submission! Care to add an explanation like other answers?

Comment: @programmer5000 I fixed an error and added the explanations

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6) / JavaScript (ES7), 52 bytes

```
f=a=>eval(`try{eval("a**2")}catch(e){Math.sqrt(a)}`)
```

Returns the square of the input in ES7 and the square root in ES6. Quite difficult to test, unless you have an older browser which support ES6 but not ES7.

```js
f=a=>eval(`try{eval("a**2")}catch(e){Math.sqrt(a)}`)

console.log(f(4));
```

Comment: Clever! Nice job on this one!

Comment: Is there a reason for the backticks? Seems like single quotes would do the job.

Comment: @JLRishe Nope, no reason :)

Comment: `a**.5` and `a*a` saves some bytes reversing type

Answer (score 5):

## C, [Operation Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Flashpoint:_Cold_War_Crisis) scripting language, 52 bytes

```
;float f(float x){return sqrt(x);}char*
F="_this^2";
```

In an OFP script, a semicolon at the beginning of a line makes that line a comment, whereas C doesn't care about the additional semicolon.

**C:**

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@2@dlpOfWKKQpgGhKzSri1JLSovyFIoLi0o0KjSta5MzEou0uNxsleJLMjKL44yUrP9n5pUo5CZm5mloclVzKQBBQRFQKE1DSTVNSQdolpGmpjVX7f9/yWk5ienF/3VzcgE)

**OFP scripting language:**

Save as `init.sqs` in the mission folder, then call it with `hint format["%1", 2 call F]`.

Result: [image]

Comment: Okay, this is pretty cool.  How'd you think of using that scritping lang?

Comment: @Riker Operation Flashpoint always was one of my favorite games; I used to do lots of stuff in it with its scripting language.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), [Grok](https://github.com/AMiller42/Grok-Language) <s><sup>10</sup></s> 12 bytes

*Edit: In my first version, I forgot that casting to `int` would remove precision in the Vyxal code. Added +2 bytes to fix it.*

```
I√`#:Yp*zq`_
```

Vyxal (Square Root):

```
              # Implicit input
I             # Cast to int
 √            # Square root
  `#:Yp*zq`   # Push string
           _  # Delete string
              # Implicit output
```

[Try it Online in Vyxal!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&code=I%E2%88%9A%60%23%3AYp*zq%60_&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

Grok (Square):

```
I√            # Push '√' to the register
  `#          # Skip ‘#’ command
    :         # Take input from STDIN
     Yp       # Duplicate
       *z     # Multiply and output as int
         q    # Quit
          `_  # Never gets executed
```

[Try it Online in Grok!](http://grok.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=I%E2%88%9A%60%23%3AYp*zq%60_&inputs=10)

Answer (score 4):

## PHP and [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>30</s> <s>29</s> 25 bytes

```
ECHO"$argv[1]"**2;#];rdmq
```

Calculates the square in PHP and the square root in CJam. Has to be run using `-r` in PHP.

#### PHP

Raises the first command line argument (`$argv[1]`) to the power 2 and outputs it. Here `$argv[1]` is actually put as an inline variable in a string, which is cast to a number before doing the exponentiation. This is because `v` is not a valid instruction in CJam and will cause it to error out while parsing, but putting it in a string won't cause any problems.

`#` starts a comment, so everything after is ignored.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCj47@rs4a@kkliUXhZtGKukpWVkrRxrXZSSW/j//39LAA)

#### CJam

The first part of the code, `ECHO"$argv[1]"**2;#` pushes a bunch of values and does a bunch of operations, all of which are thoroughly useless. The only important thing is that they doesn't cause any errors, because right afterwards is `];`, which wraps the entire stack in an array and then discards it.

After that, it reads a double from input (`rd`), and gets its square root (`mq`), and implicitly outputs it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@@/q7OGvpJJYlF4WbRirpKVlZK0ca12Uklv4/78lAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 12 bytes

```
YRTa
f(y)=yy
```

[Run in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yw4ip1tet6)

[Run in Pip](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhZrIoNCErnSNCo1bSsrIUJQmZXRxnqGJoamlrFQAQA)

#### Desmos

The first line is four undefined variables multiplied together. Desmos complains about it, but ultimately it's a no-op.

The second line defines a function `f(y)` as `y` times `y` (with an implicit multiplication operator). This function can be used in other lines and will return the square of any argument number. As a bonus, we also get to see a graph of `x = f(y)`.

#### Pip

`RTa` calculates the square root of the command-line argument `a`, and `Y` stores the result in `y`. The second line parses as three expressions:

- `f` (evaluates to the main function)
- `(y)=y` (evaluates to `1` because `y` always equals itself)
- `y` (evaluates to the value stored in `y` previously)

The last of these expressions ends the program and is therefore autoprinted.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://python.org) / [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 60 bytes

```python
#/*
n=int(input());print(n**2);"""*/
print(sqrt(input))\\"""
```

Basically a modification from the [C / Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116159/107017).
Python does square. PARI/GP does square root.
Takes input from `stdin`.

Python: [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X1lfiyvPNjOvRCMzr6C0RENT07qgCMTN09Iy0rRWUlLS0ueCiBQXFkFVaWrGxABl/v83MgUA)

PARI/GP: [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/X1lfiyvPNjOvRCMzr6C0RENT07qgCMTN09Iy0rRWUlLS0ueCiBQXFkFVaWrGxABl/v83MgUA)

Answer (score 3):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ) / QBasic, <s>26</s> 18 bytes

```
input a
?a^2'^.25
```

In **QBasic**, it takes a number, and prints that number squared. The rest of the code is ignored because QBasic sees it as a comment (`'`).

**QBIC** uses the same input statement. It then goes on to print that same number squared, then raised to the power of a quarter, effectively rooting it twice. This is because `'`is seen as a code literal: Pure QBasic code that is not parsed by QBIC.

Answer (score 3):

## [Reticular](https://tio.run/nexus/reticular#@6@vZqWl58Bll5lnla9cYP3/v6GJCQA) / [Befunge-98](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#@6@vZqWl58Bll5lnla9cYP3/v6ERAA), 15 bytes

2D languages!

```
/&:*.@
>in:o#p;
```

### Befunge-98

```
/&:*.@

/          divide top two (no-op)
 &         read decimal input
  :        duplicate
   *       square
    .      output
     @     terminate
```

### Reticular

```
/           mirror up, then right
>in:o#p;

 i          read line of input
  n         cast to number
   :o#      square root
      p     print
       ;    terminate
```

Answer (score 3):

### GolfScript/Befunge, 15 bytes

```
#>&:*.@
~2-1??
```

Befunge:

```
#>&:*.@
#>      // jumps over the arrow
  &     // takes an integer as input
   :*   // multiplies the top of the stack by itself
     .  // outputs as integer
      @ // halts
~2-1??  // is not executed
```

GolfScript:

```
#>&:*.@ // is a comment
~2-1??
~       // evaluates the input string
 2-1?   /* calculates 2^-1 = 1/2 (GolfScript does not support non-integers, but
           due to a missed int cast in the interpreter, they can be generated with
           the exponent function */
     ?  // calculates x^1/2 = sqrt(x)
        // the stack is output implicitly
```

This is my first golf, please let me know if I'm doing something wrong :)

- Edited to be more portable, thanks to Wzl

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! This looks really neat.

Comment: I believe in some befunge versions (98?) space is not an instruction, so it will skip over the `&`. Your program is working, but you could change it to another character for portability :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) and [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 10<sup>*</sup> bytes

```
<?√,;n*:
```

[Try it in Vyxal (Square root)](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiPD/iiJosO24qOiIsIiIsIjI1Il0=)

**this is 8 bytes in Vyxal but 10 in ><>. I'm scoring them both in UTF-8.*

[Try it in ><> (Square)](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiPD/iiJosO24qOiIsImlucHV0IjoiIiwic3RhY2siOiI1Iiwic3RhY2tfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyIsImlucHV0X2Zvcm1hdCI6ImNoYXJzIn0=)

## Explanation

What Vyxal sees:

```
<       # less than
 ?      # push input
  √     # sqrt
   ,    # print that sqrt
        # (rest doesn't matter)
```

What ><> sees:

```
<     # point left and wrap around executing the following
 :    # dup
  *   # multiply
   n  # output
    ; # end execution
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) and [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

[Thunno 2 encoding](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md):

```
Ẋ,$ƭ
```

[Vyxal encoding](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/blob/main/vyxal/encoding.py#L3):

```
²,$₃
```

This looks like two different programs, since Thunno 2 and Vyxal have different encodings, but it's really the same sequence of bytes.

[image: Screeshot]

(Thunno 2: square root)

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCsiwk4oKDIiwiIiwiMTAiXQ==) (Vyxal: square)

##### Explanation

```python
Ẋ,$ƭ  # Implicit input
Ẋ,    # (No effect)
  $   # Push the input
   ƭ  # Square root
      # Implicit output

²,$₃  # Implicit input
²     # Square the input
 ,    # Print the result
  $₃  # (No effect)
```

Answer (score 2):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) / [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes (7 bytes code + 2 for the '-v' flag in ><>)

Man, I'm really having fun with the Jelly link structure.

```
:*n;
½
```

Calculates the square
[in ><>](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@2@llWfNdWjv//@W/3XLLAE)
, and the square root
[in Jelly](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2@llWfNdWjv////LQE).

Comment: Are you allowed to not use the -v in jelly too?

Comment: The use of `-v` is, in my opinion, in line with the [top-voted answer[(https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11431/44874) on a meta querstion handling this case. The `><>` interpreter needs that `-v` and this is therefor the simplest possible invocation.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 + JavaScript, 101 bytes

```js
0//1or exec("function=lambda a:(lambda b:a);x=0")
y=2//2/2
f=(function(x)(x**y))//1 or(lambda x:x**y)
```

Square root in JS, square in Python.

Works on Firefox (tested on FF 52) and requires `(function(x) x)(42) === 42` being valid syntax. Also requires ES7 for the `**` operator.

Comment: Tested on Firefox and it is working. Is it possible to use `x=>x**y` instead? Or Python will choke on that?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel python doesn't support arrow functinos.

Comment: This doesn't work for python. Function isn't a keyword.

Comment: It does work. Since `function` is not a keyword, it's a valid identifier. So I just assigned a noop function to it (inside the `exec`statement).

Answer (score 2):

## bash and sh, 48 bytes

*Update: I must concede defeat. [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116292/8927)'s bash/sh answer is far more elegant than this one.*

---

```sh
bc -l<<<"sqrt($1^(($(kill -l|wc -l)*3-3)/7+1))"
```

bash produces `n^2`, sh produces `sqrt(n)`.

---

`bc` is only needed so that `sqrt` can be calculated. The difference in behaviour is between bash and sh.

OK, technically the "sh" I'm using is still bash, but bash in "POSIX" mode (which happens if you invoke `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash` on systems where `/bin/sh` is an alias for bash). If this is the case on your system, you can test with:

```sh
/bin/bash prog.sh 4
/bin/sh prog.sh 4
```

---

This is based on one of the differences explained here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @BrianMinton Try running `kill -l` (lists possible signals; doesn't change anything) in `bash` and `sh`. It's one of many differences you can find here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html

Answer (score 2):

## macOS Bash and sh, 24 bytes

```bash
p=^4 :
bc<<<"sqrt($1)$p"
```

On the Mac, `sh` is `bash` running in Posix mode, and in this case as per https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html:

> Assignment statements preceding POSIX special builtins persist in the shell environment after the builtin completes

Thus for `sh`, the variable `p` has the value `^4` after the `:` is run, but for `bash`, the variable `p` only has this value while `:` is run, and is empty afterwards.

Being still really `bash` under the covers, some bashisms such as `<<<` herestrings still work for both the bash and sh cases.

---

## Bash and dash (and GNU utils), 27

On Ubuntu 16.01, `sh` is a symlink to `dash`, which doesn't do `<<<` herestrings.  So we have this instead:

```bash
p=^4 :
echo "sqrt($1)$p"|bc
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#S04sUbCzUyguLNIrzlCwsVFQd/V3U/9fYBtnomDFlZqcka@gBJQs0VAx1FQpUKpJSv4PVMDFlZQIVA7VZcmFxP4PAA).

Comment: Nice use of a different mode/ env!

Comment: This is much better than my version!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) and [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 18 bytes

I took inspiration from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116162/103772)

```python
(1/2or 2).__rpow__
```

#### Python 3 : [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzX8NQ3yi/SMFIUy8@vqggvzw@/n9BUWZeiYZScWFRiYaxpoKtko5CGpChyYUsYWgGkwGyNP8DAA)

`1/2` is evaluated to `0.5` so `1/2or 2` is equal to `0.5` => sqrt

#### Python 2 : [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzX8NQ3yi/SMFIUy8@vqggvzw@/n9BUWZeiYKScZyRgq2SjkKahrEmF1TM0AwuaGim@R8A)

`1/2` is evaluated to `0` so `1/2or 2` is equal to `2` => ^2

Answer (score 2):

## [Java](http://jdk.java.net/) and [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 50 bytes

```java
double f(int a){return Math.pow(a, 1/2==0?2:0.5);}
```

[Try Java online!](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@X1CalJOZrJCck1hcrOCbmJlXDRUpLkksAVJl@ZkpCrlAcY3gkqLMvPTo2ETNaq7gyuKS1Fy9/NISvQKgaElOnkaahommpjVXLYr2/yn5QG6qQpoGUJECUGdRaklpUR7QopIMvYL8co1EHQVDfSNbWwN7IysDPVNN69r/tf8B)

[Try Groovy online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/Jb80KSdVIU0jM69EIVGzuii1pLQoT8E3sSRDryC/XCNRR8FQ38jW1sDeyMpAz1TTuvZ/QRFQbU6eRpqGiabmfwA)

Java squares, Groovy roots. Inspiration taken from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116162/107299), although it is unfortunate that Java does not have type coercion like Python and that Groovy has different lambdas than Java does. This works because in Java, `1/2` is equal to `0`, while in Groovy it is `0.5`.

Answer (score 2):

## C and C#, 56 bytes

```cs
double f(double x){return//\
System.Math.Sqrt(x);
x*=x;}
```

C# doesn't use `\` as a line continuation character, at least not for line comments.

[Try it in C!](https://tio.run/##LY2xDoIwFEX3fsULxqQlWBjcQP/AidWlPgo0gVbLw9QQvr1CdDu5uTkHTx1iPBiLw9xoqCZqjJP9NTZufgwaWv6HIBavafY2z@@s/kykR3lT1Mv65YkHUbKQXkK5RmMJRmUs30H5DjNAZycC7JVP0316C1gYwNNvl5Ynx6FNsq10loXYPAC/EBQlW@MX)
[Try it in C#!](https://tio.run/##LY6xDoIwFEX3fsUbWxOLgxtxcpXEhMHFpdaHNgGKrw9SQ/j2WgPbHe4959qwt54wDeOjdRZsa0KAK/kXmU7MAmAgNxlGCGzY2fT0uYjQyC1ENRPySH1R3EX9DYydrgy/df0hllGVIu5OsVxSJq2KFQSTd0@ojOulypa/CWDbn30ffIv6Ro7x4nqU2yHdyKM@qAwFWMSSfg)

I was originally going to do Swift + something else, since `/*/**/this// */` is only a comment in Swift, but it ended up being shorter to abuse C's line continuation and use another language with the same syntax.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) / [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 6 bytes

*EDIT: It's a byte shorter to reverse operations.*

```
RTa
²
```

[Try Jelly online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x8Uksh1aNP///8tAQ)

Jelly starts execution at the bottom of the code (its 'main link') and sees if it needs anything higher: it sees the command to square and takes care of input and output implicitly.

[Try Pip online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@x8Uksh1aNP///8tAQ)

Pip executes the top line, squaring the (implicitly read from the cmd line) var a and implicitly prints that. The bottom line is ignored.

Comment: Alternative 6-byter: `PRTaVS`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language](http://www.wolframalpha.com) / [PHP](http://php.net), 25 bytes

Get the square of a number in Wolfram Language and get the square root in PHP;

```
n^2
echo sqrt(_GET["n"]);
```

First line is Wolfram Language. First, you are the ones to change n in the searchbar in Wolfram Alpha so the code is also the input. Then it's will generate the answer upon pressing enter

```
n^2
```

Second line is PHP, It gets the square root of the n which is to be inputted in the address bar (eg. ppcg.php.net?n=213, where 213 is n's value)

```
echo sqrt($_GET["n"]);
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! However, you must take input somehow. You can't assume the number is stored in a variable. Sorry about that. [You can view the list of acceptable i/o methods here.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/) (positive scores on the answers mean it's allowed, negative means not allowed)

Comment: Got it. I'll just edit my answer. :) Another thing, I'll just explain why adding another code for input in wolfram is not applicable.

Comment: Happy to help! Hope you stick around in ppcg!

Comment: [Wolfram|Alpha is not a valid language.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11541/is-wolframalpha-a-valid-language)

Comment: Wolfram Language is based on mathematica which needs mathematical formula to be type in a non-natural way. Another thing, the answerer clears it out, its the website that's not the language but the wolfram language is the language that supports it. Wolfrsm Language and WolframAlpha is related to each ofher but not the same. The'yre totally different.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 5.6 and PHP 7, 55 bytes

```php
function f($n){list($a[],$a[])=[.5,2];echo $n**$a[0];}
```

PHP 5.6 produces `n^2`, PHP 7 produces `sqrt(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5.0 and Swift 5.1, 112 bytes

```swift
func f(_ x:Any)->Double{let y=x as!Double
return y*y}
func f<T>(_ x:T)->Double{return(x as!Double).squareRoot()}
```

[SwiftFiddle link](https://swiftfiddle.com/fkho4b35vfawdc3dun3xiwwebu)

Swift 5.1 changed overload resolution for functions with unlabelled arguments, so `f(_:)` resolves as the square function in Swift 5.0 and as the square root in Swift 5.1. The permissive argument types are required for this to work; if you don't pass it a double, this will compile but crash at runtime.

The lack of argument labels is required: if you remove the underscores to make this `f(x:)`, it will print the square root in both versions.

## Swift 4 and Swift 5, <s>125</s> 113 bytes

```swift
import Foundation
func s(x:Double)->Double{return pow(x,Double("\(try?{()throws->Int?in 0}())".count)*0.15-1.15)}
```

[SwiftFiddle link](https://swiftfiddle.com/n4svhocwlffsdensuyw6cjnwpi)

The function `s(x:)` computes the square in Swift 4 and the square root in Swift 5.

The original answer had the throwing function on its own line, rather than being an inline IIFE.

This was harder than I expected.

The `try?` operator is one of three legal prefixes for a call to a throwing function -- the others being `try` and `try!`. `try` requires a `catch`, `try!` promotes errors to fatal errors, and `try?` ignores errors and returns `nil` instead. For example, consider the following code snippet:

```swift
func foo() throws -> Int {
    // ...
}

let bar = try? foo()
```

The type of `bar` is now `Optional<Int>`, since it might be `nil`.

What if `foo()` already returns `Optional<Int>`? In Swift 5, the optionals are flattened, and `bar` is still `Optional<Int>`. In Swift 4, this is not the case, and `bar` is now `Optional<Optional<Int>>`.

When you convert an optional value to a string, it wraps it in `"Optional("...")"`. So, the following code:

```swift
func foo() throws -> Int? {
    return 0
}

print("\(try? foo())")
```

Prints `Optional(0)` in Swift 5 and `Optional(Optional(0))` in Swift 4. (If you don't wrap it in the string interpolation, it fails to compile. I have no idea why.)

From there, I use `.count` to get the length of the string, and do some simple arithmetic to get `2.0` in Swift 4 and `0.5` in Swift 5.

## Swift 4 and Swift 5, cheating, 85 bytes

```swift
func s(x:Double)->Double{#if swift(>=5)
return x.squareRoot()#else
return x*x#endif
}
```

I shouldn't have to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / [Cardinal](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal), 28 bytes

This program squares the input in Cardinal and gets the square root in Octave

```
 %:=t.
disp(sqrt(input("")))
```

[Try it online! (Octave)](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@6@gamVboseVkllcoFFcWFSikZlXUFqioaSkqan5/7@hgQEA)

[Try it online! (Cardinal)](https://tio.run/nexus/cardinal#@6@gamVboseVkllcoFFcWFSikZlXUFqioaSkqan5/7@hgQEA)

So % is single line comment in Octave so it just gets input and prints the square root

```
disp(sqrt(input("")))
```

So that the Cardinal program doesn't encounter a divide by 0 error and die, the program

```
%:=t.
```

has been shifted with a space, which is ignored by both programs

### Explanation of the Cardinal program:

The program starts at the %
It receives input and stores the value as active :
It sets the inactive to be equal to the active =
It multiplies the active by the inactive t
Finally it outputs the active value .

Answer (score 0):

## PHP / JavaScript, 43 bytes

```
<body onload=alert(<?=$x*$x.')>'.sqrt($x)?>
```

Input goes like:

```
<?php $x = 10; ?>
```

Kinda self-explaining, but does it fit the rules? My first code golf tho :-)

Comment: Welcome to code golf! Input must be a float or a string that is only a float. If I understand correctly, this requires separate input.

Comment: Are you sure this runs as JavaScript? It looks like both versions need a PHP processing stage (JavaScript wouldn't know what to do with `alert(<?=$x*$x.')>'.sqrt($x)?`)

Answer (score 0):

## [CGL (CGL Golfing Language)](https://codepen.io/programmer5000/pen/zwYrVd?editors=1010) / JS (ES6), 13 bytes(non-competing)

Non-competing because:

1. CGL was released after this question.
2. <s>CGL is not a [valid language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/58826).</s> Because of `＋` and `ⓟ`, CGL is technically a valid language.

### Code:

```
 x=>x**2
//-₂
```

### JS:

Simple: an anonymous arrow function that returns its first argument squared. The unnamed language code is commented out.

## CGL:

The *non-breaking space* before the first line acts like a comment. The `/`s are no-ops. The `-` in the second line means to decrement the current stack number, which by default is 0. That then sets it to -1, where input is stored. The `₂` replaces the first item in the current stack with its square root, which is now where input is placed. By default, the current stack is outputted, outputting the square root of the input.

Comment: This is 13 bytes. I dunno about CGL, but I'm fairly certain JS uses ascii/utf-8.  CGL would probably also use UTF-8, unless it has it's own codepage.

Comment: @Riker for now, it uses ascii/utf-8. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) and [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) 23 bytes

```python
#n*:i
print input()**.5
```

Python: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/XzlPyyqTq6AoM69EITOvoLREQ1NLS8/0/39OAA)

><>: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XzlPyyqTq6AoM69EITOvoLREQ1NLS8/0/39OAA)